# Respond to request after all data is inserted to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to implement multiple data insertion on one call and trigger response only after all data is inserted. This is how I am currently doing it:

```
create: function(req, res) {
    var response = {};
    var num = req.body.num;
    var ret = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var db = new user();

        db.enabled =  false;
        db.save(function(err){
            if(err) {
              // Handle error
            } else {
              ret++;
              // Do something
            }
        });
    }

    response = {"status" : 200, "message" : "It's working: " + ret};
    res.json(response);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that all the callbacks for `save` will be triggered after `res.json(response)` which is wrong because sometimes I would also like to inform user how much data was saved. User will always receive the following response:

```
It's working: 0
```

Because `ret` variable is always 0. It's getting increased only after response is already triggered. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Code after Will's suggestion:

```
var Q = require('q');

create: function(req, res) {
    var response = {};
    var num = req.body.num;
    var ret = 0;
    var tasks = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var db = new user();

        db.enabled =  false;

        tasks.push(db.save());
    }

    Q.all(tasks).then(
        function(results) { 
          response = {"status" : 200, "message" : "It's working!"}; 
        }, 
        function(err) { 
          response = {"status" : 500, "message" : "Not working!" };
        );

    res.json(response);
}
```

Comment: db.save is an async call.  You need to perform res.json in the callback.  Keep in mind though, that you will be making multiple save statements, so you'll need to add all thse db.save statements into promises and handle the promises once at the end and perform the res.json.  Google Promises and let us know if you need more help.

Comment: @Will, thank you for suggestion. I've edited my question. Can you please just confirm me this is how it should be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var db = new user();

        db.enabled =  false;
        db.save(function(err){
            if(err) {
              // Handle error
            } else {
              ret++;
              if(ret == num){
                response = {"status" : 200, "message" : "It's working: " + ret};
                res.json(response);
              }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your code would cause the send the response for every successful save in the loop.  I don't think that's what the OP wants.